# Implementing an interface in an anonymous class as an iterator: type issue

Tags: java, interface, iterator, anonymous-class

I'm having an issue with a project I'm working on. One of the things that needs to happen is to create an inspector which returns an iterator which implements an interface, while using an anonymous class. The context is a filesystem and basically, the iterator just needs to return the content of the directory the iterator works on. So here's the code I got at the moment:

Directory class:

```
public class Directory {

   ...

    public Iterator<DiskItem> iterator() {
       return new DirectoryIterator() {

            int cursor = 1;
            int end = Directory.this.getNbItems();

            public boolean hasNext() {
                return this.cursor < end;
            }

            public DiskItem next(){
                if(this.hasNext()) {
                    Directory.this.getItemAt(this.cursor++);
                }
                else
                    throw new NoSuchElementException();
            }

            @Override
            public int getNbRemainingItems() {
                return this.end - this.cursor;
            }

            @Override
            public DiskItem getCurrentItem() throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
                return Directory.this.getItemAt(this.cursor);
            }

            @Override
            public void advance() {
                if(this.hasNext()) {
                    this.cursor++;
                }
                else
                    throw new NoSuchElementException();                 
            }

            @Override
            public void reset() {
                this.cursor = 1;            
            }
        }
}
```

DirectoryIterator Interface:

```
public interface DirectoryIterator {

    int getNbRemainingItems();

    DiskItem getCurrentItem() throws IndexOutOfBoundsException;

    void advance();

    void reset();


}
```

The problem I'm having is getting the error

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from new DirectoryIterator(){} to Iterator<DiskItem>
```

and that's probably because DirectoryIterator doesn't have the type Iterator, but because it's an interface, I cannot give it any type.

Anyone an idea on how to solve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could make `DirectoryIterator` implement `Iterator<DiskItem>`

Comment: It's more an extend of DirectoryIterator from Iterator<DiskItem> rather than an implements

Comment: @PurityLake Why not make this an answer (and fix the implements vs. extends there)?

Comment: @Kayaman Ya, oops slipped up a bit there with my words, hadn't touched java in a while so it slipped my mind about implements and extends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to fix this problem would be to make `DirectoryIterator` extend `Iterator<DiskItem>`

Like this:

```
interface DirectoryIterator extend Iterator<DiskItem> {
    ...
}
```

This way `DirectoryIterator` is a subclass of `Iterator<DiskItem>` so using polymorphism we can return a `DirectoryIterator` as a `Iterator<DiskItem>`

Hope this helps, if this doesn't fix your problem be sure to leave a comment.

Comment: Thank you, the error disappeared. I did get another problem though, while testing the method iterator in the class Directory, I could only call the default methods of the Iterator class, and none of my own (the ones I implemented from the DirectoryIterator interface), for example, if I created a directory 'parent' with some files in it, I could only call next() and remove() and such, but not getNbOfRemainingItems()..

Comment: Ya, didn't think of that, well is there a reason for returning an Iterator?

Comment: Well, in the paper they clearly state: "Your solution should include an inspector which offers the ability to go through the direct content of the directory. This inspector should return an iterator, which implements the interface DirectoryIterator. Make use of an anonymous class."

Comment: Solved it, I changed the line 'public Iterator<DiskItem> iterator() {' to 'public DirectoryIterator iterator() {', and now all my functions work! This was actually my first question on stackoverflow, really surprised how fast I got a response! Thanks for the help :)